# How can I integrate Internet Banking with PaymentRequest API?

Tags: payment-request-api

With `PaymentRequest` API, I can integrate with all cards, third party application but can I integrate internet banking transactions with `PaymentRequest` API?

Answer (score 2):

The protocol is defined as [Basic Credit Transfer Payment](http://w3c.github.io/webpayments-methods-credit-transfer-direct-debit/) although no browser has implemented the feature yet. It can be available once it's implemented by a browser or one of payment apps.